# Laravel timezone issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, digital-ocean, php-7

My understanding is that it's best to save dates in UTC and convert to a user's timezone where necessary.

In my development environment (Homestead running locally) my models are saving to my database in UTC time, but in production (Digital Ocean) they're saving at local time (America/Los_Angeles).

- timezone is set to UTC in `config/app.php`
- nginx is set to UTC
- php.ini is set to UTC
- mysql global and session time_zones are set to SYSTEM

Ubuntu 16.04, nginx, PHP-7.0.8, mysql, Laravel 5.3

Anyone run in to this problem?

Comment: how about to `var_dump(date_default_timezone_get())` what it says? also laravel uses `.env`  file also what's set there?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_get()` produces UTC.  There's no timezone setting in the .env file, it's set in `config/app.php`, which I have set to UTC.

Comment: 1) Check if `/etc/timezone` shows local timezone. 2) install and start `ntp`.  3) restart PHP fpm process.

Comment: It's set to `Etc/UTC`

Comment: Server's `/etc/timezone` must show it's current location timezone. Please set it accordingly where it's located. All other time offsets are depending on that info. So fix `/etc/timezone` and restart server.

Comment: @num8er made that change but it's still saving the timestamps with my local time.  I'm curious why setting nginx to the local timezone of the server would result in my timestamps saving with UTC time.

Comment: I hope You've fixed it. if not so add me in skype: `anarjafarov` and let's collaborate

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `timezone` key in your mysql connection in the `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    /* ... */
    'timezone'  => '+00:00'
],
```